# R Match And Sub On Space Between Specific Characters

Tags: r, regex, string

I need a little help with a regular expression using `gsub`. Take this object:

`x <- "4929A 939 8229"`

I want to remove the space in between "A" and "9", but I am not sure how to match on only the space between them and not on the second space. I essentially need something like this:

`x <- gsub("A 9", "", x)`

But I am not sure how to write the regular expression to not match on the "A" and "9" and only the space between them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `sub(" ", "", x)` (not `gsub`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following regex in `sub`:

```
> x <- "4929A 939 8229"
> sub("\\s+", "", x)
[1] "4929A939 8229"
```

The `\\s+` will match 1 or more whitespace symbols.

The replacement part is an empty string.

See the [online R demo](http://ideone.com/Mbd1AW)

Comment: Just FYI: `sub` is used to only find the *first* match, and perform only a *single* regex based replacement.

Comment: To remove just the 2nd space, you would need `sub("^(\\S*\\s+\\S+)\\s+", "\\1", x)`

Comment: I addd the `+` to match one or more occurrences because I think you actually would like to match the whole chunk of whitespaces. If it is not what is intended, just remove the `+` from after `\\s` patterns.

Answer (score 2):

`gsub` matches/uses all regex found whereas `sub` only matches/uses the first one. So

```
sub(" ", "", "4929A 939 8229") # returns "4929A939 8229"
```

Will do the job

**Removing second/nth occurence**

You can do that e.g. by using `strsplit` as follows:

```
x <- c("4929A 939 8229", "4929A 9398229")

collapse_nth <- function(x_split, split, nth, replacement){
  left <- paste(x_split[seq_len(nth)], collapse = split)
  right <- paste(x_split[-seq_len(nth)], collapse = split)
  paste(left, right, sep = replacement)
}

remove_nth <- function(x, nth, split, replacement = ""){
  x_split <- strsplit(x, split, fixed = TRUE)
  x_len <- vapply(x_split, length, integer(1))
  out <- x
  out[x_len>nth] <- vapply(x_split[x_len>nth], collapse_nth, character(1), split, nth, replacement)
  out
}
```

Which gives you:

```
# > remove_nth(x, 2, " ")
# [1] "4929A 9398229" "4929A 9398229"
```

and

```
# > remove_nth(x, 2, " ", "---")
# [1] "4929A 939---8229" "4929A 9398229"
```

Comment: If you suggest replacing a *literal* space symbol, then it is better to use `sub(" ", "", x, fixed=TRUE)`

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Do you know if there is a way to do what I wanted if it were the second space I needed an not the first? Solves my problem, just want to know if there is a way.

Comment: Interesting, I like the use of strsplit here. I have similar functions I wrote awhile ago that do something similar. Just didn't think they'd be relevant here. Thanks.